# Variable considered as undefined while defined in an if structure

Tags: visual-studio, flutter

I'm quite new to Flutter and I face a small problem. Inspired by the second part of the Flutter tutorial on the official Website, I'd like to display an error message when an array is empty.

The error code is below:

```
Undefined name 'divided'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

The code is:

```
void _showSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          if (_saved.isEmpty) {
            final Text divided = Text('List is empty');
          } else {
            final Iterable<ListTile> tiles = _saved.map(
              (WordPair pair) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    pair.asPascalCase,
                    style: _biggerFont,
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
            final ListView divided = ListView(
                children: ListTile.divideTiles(
              context: context,
              tiles: tiles,
            ).toList());
          }

          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Saved Suggestions'),
              ),
              //body: _saved.isEmpty ? Text('List is empty') : ListView(children: divided),
              body: divided);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

The variable is defined in an if condition, but VSCode still displays an error that the variable is undefined. Is there something I don't understand properly?

For your information, working with the inline condition does work (commented line in code sample).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable divided is scoped only between the braces of the if and the else blocks
defining it like this solves the problem:

```
void _showSaved() {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        var divided;
        if (_saved.isEmpty) {
          divided = Text('List is empty');
        } else {
          final Iterable<ListTile> tiles = _saved.map(
                (WordPair pair) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  pair.asPascalCase,
                  style: _biggerFont,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
          divided = ListView(
              children: ListTile.divideTiles(
                context: context,
                tiles: tiles,
              ).toList());
        }

        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Saved Suggestions'),
            ),
            //body: _saved.isEmpty ? Text('List is empty') : ListView(children: divided),
            body: divided);
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: So simple. I did try to define it but I didn't use the keyword "var". Thank you.

Comment: It's ok dart can be confusing if you come from java bg for example
but it will be nice and fun later